# animating with .animate() jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I have a logo/header in a css

```
#logo2 {padding:43px 20px 0 20px; background:url(images/in_Store_Marketing.jpg) top right no-repeat;}
```

I am trying to use .animate() in jquery to make the logo come from the right side of the screen and settle in on the left side of the screen.  Using the css above, it sets the image on the left side, where it should be at the end of animation.

currently the jquery looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#logo2').animate(
     { right: "+=95%" }, 3000 );
});
```

HTML looks like this

```
<div id="logo2" style="height:70px">
```

it currently does nothing, no animation... what am I missing?  How would you get this to work do animate in such a way?

Comment: To format code properly, just paste it into the text edit box and then click the **{}** thing in the row of tools above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this?

```
.logo {padding: 35px 15 px 0 15 px; background:url(images/Logo.jpg) top right no-repeat;}
```

Notice i changed left to **right**

and change the js to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $('#alex').animate({ right: "+=95%" }, 3000); });
```

I've coded a similar example for you in jsfiddle, [check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/YNyj6/)

**UPDATE:**

Try my update, it uses a absolutly positioned image, that will give the same effect as a background image:

[http://jsfiddle.net/tub3c/](http://jsfiddle.net/tub3c/1/)

Comment: thanks for the quick response, I tried what you said but it didn't work.  I went ahead updated the code in the question to include your suggested modifications, any thoughts on why it is not working?  Thank you, kindly.

Comment: Check my updated answer. It uses and absolutly positioned image instead.

Answer (score 1):

You're animating "left", but you really need to animate "background-position".  However, as that's not one of the basic sort of properties that jQuery can directly animate, it may be necessary to also load jQueryUI, and even it may not be able to animate "background-position" (the problem being that it's a weird two-valued property).

Answer (score 1):

i think left needs to be in quotes:

```
$(".logo").animate({"left": "+=400px"}, 3000);
```

Also, animate() edits position and you do not have any position set and as far as I know it only moves elements not objects inside elements.

if you look at this fiddle I changed your css a little to add the positioning and I wrapped the "logo" in a div which the animation is applied to.

hope this helps. 
http://jsfiddle.net/aMaaC/1/

Comment: tried this, it did not work.  Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: Also, I spaced out a bit you want it to go from right to left.  I updated the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/aMaaC/2/

The animation code is a little weird sometimes you need to do left -= to make the element go to the left.  I also floated the logo to the right of the screen.

Comment: Thank you for the follow up, I did get it to animate.  However, it is not properly set within the div, and it is "bleeding" and pushing other images down as it animates.  any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @user630581, please check out my answer, i think its a better solution to your requirements.

Comment: This is probably caused by more positioning issues.  Are the images being pushed around inside of the same div as the animated logo?  If so I would pull them out and place them in another div below the header.  Then set the height to a fixed size.  You could also look into layering divs with the z-index property.  Also, originally I suggested using relative positioning, depending on how many elements are in the vicinity, absolute positioning may be a better option.

Comment: @Alex I try to avoid absolute positioning whenever possible, but I do agree with you it may be better suited in this case.

Answer (score 1):

An elements "position" property must be set to something other than "static" for placement properties like "top" or "left" to have any effect (note that position defaults to "static" unless defined otherwise - which is whats causing the OPs issues). So: absolute, relative, and maybe fixed (not positive on that one). Also - jquery will definitely animate "background-position", but *only* one parameter, and not two ( "-30px", and not "-30px 10px"). In jQ 1.4, you could animate both parts, but its been "fixed" in 1.5. Kinda sadly.